# Should ossia stave barlines connect to main stave?

Tags: notation

I'm arranging some string-quartet music; I have been asked to do an ossia part for a section of Violin I. Should ossia staves have barlines that connect to the main stave:

[image]

or barlines that don't:

[image]

I'm using Sibelius and it defaults to the latter...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is adapted from *Behind Bars* by Elaine Gould (a very comprehensive guide on notation):

> A solid barline connects both staves at the beginning of a system. When the ossia stave begins mid-system at a barline, most editions do not include the initial barline through the cue stave: the dotted barline occupies only the space between the two staves.
>
> When starting mid-bar, there is no connecting barline; it is free-floating.

So given your case, I would just use a short dotted line connecting the two staves in lieu of a measure line.

Also, I'm not sure I understand why you're using a double-bar there? Is there a tempo change? Also, you may want to consider putting the "Violin I - ossia" to the left of the staff instead of above.